# Rails First Run Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've started to work with the basic tutorial (Yes I'm fresh..)
I'm getting the error when trying to run **"rails db:create"**

```
could not find activesupport-3.1.2.rc2 in any of the sources
run 'bundle install' to install
```

I've tried to install all the bundles and the specific gem (and getting: "could not get valid gem") and I'm still getting this error.

Any Ideas?

Comment: which version of ruby and rails are you using? what platform?

Comment: Please tell us your OS, which version of ruby are you using, and if you are using a tool like RVM or rbenv

Answer (score 0):

You may be using a version (did you actually run `rake db:create`?) which wasn't installed with bundler. Try using the following:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```